# Using pure virtual classes to create vectors (template)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I currently have a base class called Shape that I made a pure virtual function.

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    float area;
    float perimeter;

public:
    virtual float calcArea() = 0;
    virtual float calcPerimeter() = 0;
    virtual void printArea() = 0;
    virtual void printPerimeter() = 0;
};
```

And I created two classes as such

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(float x);
    ~Circle();

    float calcPerimeter();
    float calcArea();
    void printPerimeter();
    void printArea();

private:
    float radius;
};
```

and

```
class Square : public Shape
{
public:
    Square(float x);
    ~Square();

    float calcPerimeter();
    float calcArea();
    void printPerimeter();
    void printArea();

private:
    float length;
};
```

However when I tried to create a vector of type Shape it said virtual objects could not be instantiated "Shape cannot instantiate abstract class"

```
std::vector<Shape> shapeVector;
```

I'm not actually creating an "object" as I'm only creating a vector of type shape and adding in Circle and Square. So why does this not work? I'm aware that if I make Shape not a pure virtual class I can inherit.

My logic is that there's no reason for me to instantiate a class of type "Shape" ever so I made it pure virtual but I still want to use a Shape vector to store my derived classes.

**Full main function here**

```
Square square(3);
Circle circle(5);

square.calcArea();
square.calcPerimeter();

circle.calcArea();
circle.calcPerimeter();


std::vector<Shape> shapeVector;

shapeVector.push_back(square);
shapeVector.push_back(circle);

for (int i = 0;  shapeVector.size(); i++) {
    shapeVector[i].printArea();
    shapeVector[i].printPerimeter();
}
```

Comment: You can reduce your problem to a simpler example (that also doesn't work): it's like trying to have `Shape s = Square(3);`. If you understand that example and everything that's wrong with it, you also understand the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement "I'm not actually creating an "object" as I'm only creating a vector of type shape and adding in Circle and Square." Is incorrect. You are creating a vector of actual `Shape` objects. Since you can't instantiate `Shape` this is why you get the error. You'll need to use `Shape*` (or more likely a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` around Shape) as your template type.

Think of it in terms of a primitive type as the template type. If you used `vector<int>` you are getting actual ints within the vector. The same idea holds true for objects.

Comment: Ah yes! You're right. Thanks for the explanation :)